# Adding a scrollbar to GUI labels not working

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried adding a scrollbar to my GUI but it keeps returning a small canvas which my labels don't fit.
Below is my code using Python.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, Frame, ttk
from tkinter.constants import ANCHOR, BOTH, LEFT, RIGHT, VERTICAL, Y


root = tk.Tk()

#create a Main Frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_frame.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5,0), sticky="nw")
main_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
main_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


#create a canvas
my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame, bg="yellow")
my_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")


#Scrollbar
my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")

#configure the canvas
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))
#create another frame inside canvas
second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)
#add that new frame to a window in the canvas
my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=second_frame, anchor="nw")

# Labels
tk.Label(root, text="Decision Support System").grid(
    column=0, row=0, sticky="", padx=50)
tk.Label(root, text="""This is a simple application that will help in decision making on whether to adopt a technology based on criteria listed below, you are rate each criteria 1-5
1- not important, 2- slightly important, 3- moderately important, 4-important, 5- very important""").grid(column=0, row=1)
tk.Label(root, text="What type of technology are you trying to invest in?").grid(
    column=0, row=2, sticky="w", pady=20, padx=10)
tk.Label(root, text="CA1- Technology Predictors, Group score[35], Coefficient = 0.200").grid(
    column=0, row=3, sticky="", pady=10, padx=10)
tk.Label(root, text="Ca1.1-Level of training required :  is training of staff going to be thorough?").grid(
    column=0, row=4, sticky="w", pady=10, padx=10)


#GUI window
root.mainloop()
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image: tkwindow]

It has a total of 27 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

I've added a horizontal scrollbar and placed all labels into canvas.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Canvas, Frame, ttk
from tkinter.constants import ANCHOR, BOTH, LEFT, RIGHT, VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL, X, Y

root = tk.Tk()

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

my_canvas = Canvas(root, bg = "yellow")
my_canvas.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")

#Scrollbar
v_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient = VERTICAL, command = my_canvas.yview)
v_scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky="ns")
my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = v_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

#Scrollbar
h_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient = HORIZONTAL, command = my_canvas.xview)
h_scrollbar.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="ew")
my_canvas.configure(xscrollcommand = h_scrollbar.set)
my_canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

#create a Main Frame
main_frame = tk.Frame(my_canvas)
main_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

# Labels
tk.Label(main_frame, text = "Decision Support System").grid(
    column = 0, row = 0, sticky = "", padx = 50)
tk.Label(main_frame, text="""This is a simple application that will help in decision making on whether to adopt a technology based on criteria listed below, you are rate each criteria 1-5
1- not important, 2- slightly important, 3- moderately important, 4-important, 5- very important""").grid(
    column = 0, row = 1)
tk.Label(main_frame, text="What type of technology are you trying to invest in?").grid(
    column = 0, row = 2, sticky="w", pady = 20, padx = 10)
tk.Label(main_frame, text="CA1- Technology Predictors, Group score[35], Coefficient = 0.200").grid(
    column = 0, row = 3, sticky="", pady = 10, padx = 10)
tk.Label(main_frame, text="Ca1.1-Level of training required :  is training of staff going to be thorough?").grid(
    column = 0, row = 4, sticky = "w", pady = 10, padx = 10)

my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window = main_frame, anchor = "nw")

root.geometry("836x221")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i have 27 rows for labels currently the window when maximize shows only some rows i want to able to scroll down and up all my labels pls. Thanks

Comment: You should be able in insert as many labels as you want, just make sure they have  unique row values, also the root window can now be resized.